# Rspec: controller action not rerouting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I've set up a MoviesController with "director" and "index" actions. Here is the "director" action.

[director action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cWD8.png)

I'm running rspec tests on the "director" action.

[director test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCvGO.png)

I get this error

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA6bZ.png)

The error is saying @similarMovies is nil, but before that line, I test if @similarMovies is nil and redirect to the index action (movies_path). I've manually tested this code, and I do get redirected if @similarMovies is nil. I've used byebug, and it does indeed go in the "if @similarMovies == nil" block. The redirect_to method even gets called, but for some reason, it never actually gets redirected to the index action. I know this because I put byebug at the beginning of the index action as well. I'm very confused by this behaviour. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add code instead of images. it would help others. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

change your if condition to check for `empty?` not `== nil`. If no records are found you still receive an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

```
if @similarMovies.empty?
  flash[:notice] = "'#{@movie.title}' has no director info"
  redirect_to movies_path and return
end
```